# What is the best way to filter errors/failures in JUnit files?

Tags: java, junit, continuous

My division uses continuous integration but our product and process don't lend well to the model that bugs should be fixed immediately (long runtimes, shared resources, old VCS tools, etc). CI is still useful for detecting problems quickly and identifying the culprits though. I have a script which can read the JUnit XML file and determine which failures to filter and write a new filtered output file but I'd like to include information in the file which can be seen in CI tools which explains why it was filtered. Unfortunately, the testcase and testsuite elements seem to lack a  node. Is there a place in the format where I can place this information?

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="name">
    <testcase name="name">
      <failure>some message</failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Into something like:

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="name">
    <testcase name="name">
      <failure>some message
Filtered: See bug #####</failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify the test. If the current code is

```
Assert.fail("some message")
```

change it to

```
Assert.fail("some message\nFiltered: See bug #####")
```

You can add a message to assert... methods, too. Use

```
Assert.assertEquals("Filtered: See bug #####", expectedValue, actualValue)
```

instead of

```
Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue)
```

Comment: The filters are applied post-testing so I can't modify the tests. I already have a script which modifies the JUnit file to attach the messages as described. However, the problem that I have is the file is read by a CI tool and it still sees the test as failing. I could just remove the <failure> node but then I won't have any details about there being a failure and that it was filtered. <stdout> seems to only apply to testsuite, no?